# How to reduce the gap between plot title text and the legend in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I reduce the gap between plot title text and the legend in `gnuplot` ?
For example in the following plot how do I reduce the gap between **ABC*** and circle symbol?
[image]
I am using `ubuntu` version `18.04` and `gnuplot` version `5.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of customization options for the legend.  One way to do it is to reduce the total width ("sample length") allocated for the symbol.

```
 set key samplen 0.5      # reduce sample length to half the default
```

Comment: Thanks once again. It has worked the way I expected.